# Truncate a string inside an Excel cell if the char count is greater than than a value

Tags: string, excel, count, trunk

In Excel, for each row of the sheet I have various length strings (a1,a2,a3...). In cell B2 I have `=Length(A1)` to count the chars inside the string.

I need a formula/function that can truncate all strings in column A which have a character count > 20 
Something like:

```
$string = THIS IS A LONG STRING I WANT TO TRUNCATE IF EXCEEDS 20 CHARS;
if ($string > 20)
{
   COUNT 20 CHARS FROM THE BEGINNING OF STRING AND CUT THE REST
} 
else 
{
 skip 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just read the 1st 20 characters, it doesn't matter if there are fewer;

```
 =left(A1, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
=LEFT(DataCell,20)
```

eg:

```
=LEFT(A1,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Len` function for Length and `Left` function to use only the first 20 caracters:

```
Dim myString As String

If (Len(myString) > 20) Then
    myString = Left(myString, 20)
End If
```